# Remove all lines from a file, starting and ending with a specific string

Tags: linux, bash

I need to check if a file contains a specific two strings and if it does, remove all the text between them (strings included). Let's say I have a file `text` which looks something like this:

```
line of text
line of text
line of text
line of text
#1st string
line of text
line of text
line of text
#2nd string
```

Now I would like to delete all the lines between `#1st string` and `#2nd string` and those two strings included.

I tried getting the whole text into a variable and then removing them like that:

```sh
prefix="#1st string"
suffix="#2nd string"

#content of a file into variable
tempfile=$( cat text )
tempfile=${tempfile#"$prefix"}
tempfile=${tempfile%"$suffix"}
echo ${tempfile}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because the text file contains some commands which somehow list the content of the current directory and blend the output into the variable which leaves the file corrupted. Can I prevent that somehow, or is there a better way of achieving this altogether?

Comment: As an aside, the reason why you see the contents if you directory is likely because your file contains a `*` wildcard character, and the unquoted expansion results in it being expanded to all filenames in the current directory.

Comment: Yes I can confirm that to be the case

Comment: Following up BenjaminW's comment: variable references should almost always be double-quoted. See ["I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) and ["When is double-quoting necessary?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use sed to remove the line range:

```sh
sed '/#1st string/,/#2nd string/d' text
```

To store the result in-place, use

```sh
sed -i '/#1st string/,/#2nd string/d' text
```

or the more portable

```sh
sed '/#1st string/,/#2nd string/d' text > tempfile && mv tempfile text
```

And finally, because you might have files where only the first string exists, you have to check existence of the second string first:

```sh
grep -q '#2nd string' text && sed '/#1st string/,/#2nd string/d' text
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use grep's before and after feature:

```
prefix="#1st string"
suffix="#2nd string"

grep -B 100000000 $prefix text | grep -v $prefix > output
grep -A 100000000 $suffix text | grep -v $suffix >> output
```